# .NET WCF class calling Java created WSDL, "References a method and a type" error

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

I have spent the last couple of days trying to call a third party web service written in Java from .NET.

I have used the svcutil.exe utility to create a proxy class to call the web service.

I am refraining from posting the WSDL as it is 2,785 lines long. The generated proxy class is 8,560 lines long so I'm also refraining from posting that, however I'll post some of the highlights below and what I've been doing to try to resolve the issue.

The SOAP which the web service is expecting (namespaces trimmed for brevity) looks like this:

```
<s:Envelope>
  <s:Header> ... </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <GetAccountDetail>
      <Request>
        ...
      </Request>
    </GetAccountDetail>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The SOAP which the web service then returns, looks like this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
  <SOAP-ENV:Header />
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <gad:GetAccountDetail>
      <gad:Response>
        ...
      </gad:Response>
    </gad:GetAccountDetail>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

As you can see the request goes in via a `<GetAccountDetail>/<Request>` element, and a response comes out via a `<GetAccountDetail>/<Response>` element. The difference appears to be the gad: prefix that is used on the response.

That in mind, here is the signature of one of the class files that svcutil created for the Request

```
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(), _
 System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0"), _
 System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced), _
 System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName:="GetAccountDetail", WrapperNamespace:="http://www.mysite.co.uk/NAC/GetAccountDetail", IsWrapped:=True)> _
Partial Public Class GetAccountDetailWSDLRequest
```

And here is the signature of the response

```
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(), _
 System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0"), _
 System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced), _
 System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName:="GetAccountDetail", WrapperNamespace:="http://www.mysite.co.uk/NAC/GetAccountDetail", IsWrapped:=True)> _
Partial Public Class GetAccountDetailWSDLResponse
```

As you can see, both the classes share this decoration:
`WrapperName:="GetAccountDetail",WrapperNamespace:="http://www.mysite.co.uk/NAC/GetAccountDetail", IsWrapped:=True`

I am getting the following error at runtime:

**The XML element 'GetAccountDetail' from namespace 'http://www.mysite.co.uk/NAC/GetAccountDetail' references a method and a type. Change the method's message name using WebMethodAttribute or change the type's root element using the XmlRootAttribute.**

After plenty of digging around, I have discovered that if I change either the wrapper name or the wrapper namespace on either of the above classes, that this error goes away. However this gives me one of two major issues.

1. If I change the WrapperName/WrapperNamespace on the request class, whilst I can then get a response from my proxy class, it is always a web-service generated error saying that I didn't pass the right information in the request (when you look in Fiddler it's clear why, the XML element name is wrong)
2. If I change the WrapperName/WrapperNamespace on the response class, I can then send the request perfectly and I can see the request and response in Fiddler are correct - the web service gets the request, understands it, sends a valid response with loads of data. But I then can't get hold of that in .NET because the mappings are wrong.

So, it feels like I need to keep both the WrapperName and WrapperNamespaces like the proxy created it, but that gives the error in bold above.

By the way amending the WSDL is not an option unfortunately.

I have also tried using the wsdl.exe tool instead of svcutil.exe tool. This gives a similar problem telling me that the method cannot be reflected, with an InnerException that the XML element references a method and a type.

As I've said due to the sheer size of the wsdl and proxy classes I'm not posting them here and they're not available to link to as they're not on an external server. But if it will help to post certain sections of it let me know and I'll try and arrange it.

Comment: SO, do you have any final solution for this?
I have the same problem.

Comment: I wish that I did. I had to build all the SOAP manually and send it with a `WebClient` #frown